# Trying to 'alias' a polymorphic has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :tracked_locations, through: :tracks, source: :tracking, source_type: 'Location'
```

and a `Track` model (think of it as 'following'):

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tracking, polymorphic: true
end
```

The idea here is I will have many models to track / follow so I am using polymorphism.  For example I have a `Location` model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks, :as => :tracking, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :tracks
```

Now in the console `Location.first.users` works fine along with `User.first.tracked_locations`.

Now I will be adding another polymorphic relationship along the lines of `Flagged`.  The user can 'flag' another model with a note etc.  So if I add `has_many :users, through: :flagged` to the `Location` model for example I need to differentiate between tracking users and flagged users.

I tried:

```
  has_many :tracking_users, through: :tracks, source: :tracking, source_type: 'User'
```

but I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `evaluators_for' for #<Location:0x007ff29e5409c8>
```

Can I even do this or am I missing something simple here?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer below I figured it out:

```
has_many :tracking_users, through: :tracks, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", source: :user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but you could try:

```
has_many :tracking_users, through: :tracks, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", source: :user
```

Or you could also just create a class method and do it by hand.

```
def self.tracking_users
  user_ids = tracks.collect(&:user_id)
  User.where(id: user_ids)
end
```

edit: Had a brainfart, changed the "source" up there to :user. That tells what table to actually do the lookup in with the other attribute you've provided. of course it wouldn't be in :tracks

Comment: Close but the errors it threw pointed me in the right direction for a guess: has_many :tracking_users, through: :tracks, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", source: :user which works